# Linux run scripts one after other in loop

Tags: linux, loops

I have 10 scripts 1.sh ... 10.sh in one folder.
I want to run them one after another and starts from the beggining in loop. For example
./1.sh 
when finish
./2.sh
and so on till run
./10.sh
finish and automatically starts again ./1.sh

Comment: Forever. I will stop it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((;;)); do
    for i in {1..10}; do
        ./${i}.sh
    done
done
```